# stop the glass-fish server after closing the tab of the web application in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans-7, glassfish-4

like stopping the java application by clicking on the applet close using mouse listener, is there a way to listen mouse from browser.

if it is there, then it should be able to stop the running server of the respective web application?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just search the instance of Java that is running GlassFish (using the OS Task Manager), and kill it.